# datamash crosstab with counts per row, per column; post-sorted

Tags: text-processing, datamash

For a huge list of pairs each looking like

```
incident_N, name_M
```

...I need to create an "advanced" cross-table with `datamash`:

- for each `incident`, it should also show count of `name`s involved
- for each `name`, it should also show count of `incident`s where it is involved

After that, rows and columns should ideally be sorted by number of "involvements": see row / column highlighted in yellow in the sample table below:

[image: Ideal expected output]

Comment: Hello, your sample table is quite hard to read. Could you please add some text-formatted input file and an expexted output too ? and what have you tried so far ?

Comment: For that exact output, I think you'll have to write a custom awk/perl/python script. AFAIK, `datamash` doesn't support printing the counts for either the X or Y axis. You might be able to do it with `pandas`'s [crosstab](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) function, or in [R](https://www.r-project.org/) with the [crosstab](https://cran.r-project.org/web//packages/crosstable) package. GNU's [Octave](https://octave.org/) and [PSPP](https://www.gnu.org/software/pspp/) also have support for crosstabs. It's a common feature in many stats programs.

Comment: You could use datamash to produce the basic crosstab and then post-process the output with an awk or perl script to add a column and row for the counts (that might be a bit simpler than re-implementing crosstabs yourself).